# Android Studio Libgdx Sprite/Texture Transparency

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite, transparency, opacity

I need to change the transparency of a texture/sprite and I really have no idea how to do it. Any help?

Comment: You really should google this before asking. There's already a bunch of documentation, guides and so on, on how to do this.

Comment: I really googled before asking this and I didn't found anything. I was surprised too. Can you help me please?

Comment: Alright. What exactly do you want to do? Change the transparency of a texture while the game is running?

Comment: Yes. Like a block which is falling

Answer (score 4):

I see two solutions here - one is to change transparency directly in sprite:

```
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite( yourTexture );              
    Sprite otherSprite = new Sprite( yourOtherTexture );

    sprite.setAlpha(0.1f); // 0f is full transparent when 1f is full visible

    ...

    batch.begin();

    sprite.draw( batch ); //this one will be almost transparent
    otherSprite.draw( batch ); //this one will be normal

    batch.end();
```

you can always manipulate with **Sprite** color directly:

```
    sprite.setColor( sprite.getColor.r, sprite.getColor.g, sprite.getColor.b, 0.1f);
```

but it seems to be a silly way for me.

The second one which I recommend is to wrap your **Sprite** into **Scene2d Actor class** like for example **Image**. Then you can still change aplha directly but you are also able to use Scene2d **Actions** mechanism, manipulating actor's alpha smoothly (like alpha changing animation step by step).

Both **Scene2d** and **Actions** are to wide to describe it here but I encourage you to read about it here:

- [Scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d)
- [Scene2d Actions](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-2-Actions.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my GameRenderer.java:

```
private void drawTapTapChuggy() {
    batcher.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5f);
    batcher.draw(AssetLoader.tapTapChuggy, 28, 89, (83 * 0.9f), (52 * 0.9f));
    batcher.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1.0f);
}
```